# busca não esta retornando os dados php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

pessoal estou fazendo uma pagina de busca so que quando faço a busca não esta retornando os dados poderiam me ajudar?
no que estou errando?

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conn2.php'); ?>

<?php 


$tipo_prod = $_POST['tipo_prod'];

echo $tipo_prod;

if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$result = $conn1->query('SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE tipo_prod = '.$tipo_prod.''); 

if ($result > 0) {                  

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>



  <section>
  <div class="container py-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="upload/<?php echo $variavel_limpa ?>-padrao.jpg" class="w-100">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
            <div class="card-block px-3">
              <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['nome_prod']; ?></h4>
              <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['tipo_prod']; ?></p>
              <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['desc_prod']; ?></p>
                <!-- Divider -->
        <hr class="my-3">
                <strong>Tamanho (Altura X Largura): </strong><?php echo $row['tamanho1_prod']; ?> X <?php echo $row['tamanho2_prod']; ?>
                <div><strong>Preço do metro²:</strong> R$<?php echo $row['pre_metro2']; ?></div>
                <div><strong>Custo do Produto:</strong> R$<?php echo $row['custo_produto']; ?></div>
               <div><strong>Valor da unidade:</strong> R$<?php echo $row['valor_uni']; ?></div>
                 <!-- Divider -->
        <hr class="my-3">
                <div><strong>Codigo do produto:</strong> <?php echo $row['codigo_prod']; ?></div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
        </div>


</section>




<?php }
 } else {
    echo "<center>"."<h1>"."Não há produtos!"."<div>"."<small class="."text-muted".">"."Cadastre um para visualizar!"."</small>"."</div>"."</h1>"."</center>";
 }

$conn1->close();

?>
```

conn2

```
<?php
        //cria a conexao mysqli_connect('localizacao BD', 'usuario de acesso', 'senha', 'banco de dados')
        $conn1 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'gr1');

        //ajusta o charset de comunicação entre a aplicação e o banco de dados


        //verifica a conexão
        if ($conn1->connect_error) {
            die("Falha ao realizar a conexão: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

Comment: $result->num_rows

Comment: eu fiz a alteração e da esse erro Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\xampp 5\htdocs\gp1\mostra_prod.php
on line
16

Comment: Coloque o código de Connections/conn2.php

Comment: prontinho esta acima

Comment: Faça um var_dump do $result

Comment: Lonabool(false) 
Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\xampp 5\htdocs\gp1\mostra_prod.php
on line
16

Comment: qual o tupo do campo tipo_prod

Comment: ele é do tipo: text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *query* não está bem construído

No  query esta a usar a cláusula WHERE compara com um campo do tipo texto por isso terá que envolver o valor de comparação entre '', ex. 'valor'

exemplo:

```
$tipo_prod="tipo1"

$result = $conn1->query("SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE tipo_prod = '$tipo_prod'");
```

Aconselho também a ler sobre *sql injection*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: entendi, não vi as aspas simples, mas muito obrigado por te me ajudado, havia usado um codigo semelhante pra buscar uma id